# read objectURL in get instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I always want something different.

At this point I am creating a page with scraps from other pages.
In order for users to be able to print this page I am creating a Object URl with the blob of the page in it.
This blob is sent to another page. This all goes well.
accept for reading this URL into the new page.

To explain what I am doing here some code:

```
var pageBlob = new Blob([$('body').html()], {type: 'text/html'});
var url = 'report.html?page=' + URL.createObjectURL(pageBlob);
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

This works now in report.html I would like to show the data in this blob and 
also use some stylesheets.

I can get the blob just fine an place it (per example) in an iFrame.
But in an iFrame I can't set styles. So I just don't seem to get passed this problem.

So for now I only have this in the report.html:

```
var url = window.location.search.replace("?page=", "");
```

I tried to figfure out of there is a way to read the url back to a blob or into a string so I can override the body of the html.

No luck so far, so maybe you know how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get the data i Need.

I using jQueries Get to read the page:

```
var url = window.location.search.replace("?page=", "");
$.get(url, function (data) {
   $('body').html(data);
});
```

thats it, placed this in a script tag in the header.